# How do I configure Typescript React App created with create-react-app to emit the files to particular directory with yarn start (dev mode)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, create-react-app, webpack-dev-server

I have a React App (Typescript templated created using `create-react-app`) which emits all the changes to `localhost:3000` when I execute yarn start. All local changes are immediately served with hot loading.

I have another local dev server running which consumes this app's react files in `/build`  (output from `yarn build`).

I would like to see all my compiled changes emitted by `yarn start` be consumed by another server running locally. in other words, I want the `yarn to start` to emit the change to my file system so they can be served.

I tried ejecting the project and changing configuration files to emit to the build directory with `yarn start` but that does not work.

I have also tried switching my project to https://neutrinojs.org but that may not be an option for me at moment.

Could someone suggest what approach should I be taking to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.
I used https://www.npmjs.com/package/cra-build-watch which serves the purpose